# mobiscroll change the text of an option

Tags: jquery, html, mobiscroll

If I use the following code I am able to change the text of a standard option:

```
$("#test option[value='100']").text("NEW TEXT");
```

This code does not work on options that are using mobiscroll. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dqT9m/

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#sel').mobiscroll().select({
        theme: 'ios',
        display: 'inline',
        mode: 'scroller',
        inputClass: 'i-txt',
        width: 200
    });  
    $("#sel").find("option[value='0']").text("NEW TEXT");
    $("#sel").parent().find('[data-val="_0"] div').text("NEW TEXT");
});
```

It is not enough to change option value, you also need to change plugin widget visible value.